# Remove Index from MVC url with routeValue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can I remove the Index from the MVC url that has a routeValue?

E.g.
http://localhost/Beverage/Index/WhiteWine
to 
http://localhost/Beverage/WhiteWine

but still be able to have
http://localhost/Beverage/ShowBeverage/1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a custom route:

```
MapRoute("My Route Name",
         "Beverage/{id}",
         new { controller = "Beverage", action = "Index" });
```

Note that the controller name must be hard-coded in the route, then specified in the defaults to tell MVC which controller to use.
If you take the naive approach and map `{controller}/{id}`, it will accept any URL of the form `a/b`, which is not what you want.

Comment: This doesn't work. ActionLinks don't update and if I remove the Index from the url it 404s. I am new to routes in MVC so I may be missing a step.

Comment: @Jamie: Put this before your other routes, or it will caught by the general route first.

Comment: Brilliant that was the step I missed